# Как вывести в одну строку текст, переменную и текст?

Tags: c++, строки, потоки-данных, вывод

Пробовал

```
std::cout << "text" + num_1 + "text2" << std::endl;
```

не компилируется

Answer (score 4):

```
std::cout << "text" << num_1 << "text2" << std::endl;
```